# React Native TouchableOpacity not working after setting styles of text

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, react-native-stylesheet

Hi I am new with React Native I've made a form and at the bottom of form I've added these lines **New here? Create an account** which on clicking "Create an account" text it should navigate on the directed screen.. but as soon as I'have added the styles to it, its not working.
Here's my code:

```
<Text style={{left:70,top:40,color:'#898989'}}>New here?</Text>
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('SignUp')}>
    <Text style={{marginLeft:145,top:17,fontSize:15,color:'#FB7956'}}>Create an account</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add marginLeft and top property in TouchableOpacity style and remove from text style.

```
<TouchableOpacity 
onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('SignUp')} 
style={{marginLeft:145,top:17}}>
    <Text style={{fontSize:15, color:'#FB7956'}}>Create an account</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```